# Webhook : how to display the response in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, webhooks

I'm working with an API that allow me to check if a user is connected to any account (Amazon, Ebay, Prestashop, etc). 
When a connection is made, I receive a webhook in `JSON` that looks like this :

```
 Parameters: {"connection"=>{"informations"=>{}, "connector_uuid"=>"3180ba23-2b75-5abe-b14d-69a42835474d", "id_user"=>626, "created"=>"2019-12-26 10:03:41", "id_provider"=>940, "error_message"=>nil, "last_push"=>nil, "last_update"=>"2019-12-26 10:03:45", "connector"=>{"sync_frequency"=>nil, "code"=>nil, "uuid"=>"3180ba23-2b75-5abe-b14d-69a42835474d", "documents_type"=>["bill"], "color"=>"c8ee20", "auth_mechanism"=>"credentials", "capabilities"=>["document"], "id"=>470, "available_auth_mechanisms"=>["credentials"], "beta"=>true, "months_to_fetch"=>nil, "urls"=>["https://addons.prestashop.com"], "siret"=>nil, "hidden"=>false, "charged"=>true, "slug"=>"PRE", "categories"=>[], "name"=>"PrestaShop"}, "active"=>true, "state"=>nil, "expire"=>nil, "accounts"=>[], "error"=>nil, "subscriptions"=>[{"id_source"=>604, "documents"=>[], "id_user"=>696, "deleted"=>nil, "id_connection"=>708, "number"=>"test01@gmail.com", "validity"=>nil, "label"=>"test@gmail.com", "subscriber"=>"John Doe", "currency"=>nil, "disabled"=>nil, "error"=>"bug", "id"=>550, "formatted_balance"=>nil, "renewdate"=>nil, "balance"=>nil, "last_update"=>nil}], "next_try"=>"2019-12-27 14:03:45", "id_connector"=>440, "id"=>608}, "push_type"=>"partial_history", "user"=>{"signin"=>"2019-12-26 10:03:08", "platform"=>"sharedAccess", "id"=>626}, "invoice"=>{"connection"=>{"informations"=>{}, "connector_uuid"=>"3180ba23-2b75-5abe-b14d-69a42835474d", "id_user"=>926, "created"=>"2019-12-26 10:03:41", "id_provider"=>480, "error_message"=>nil, "last_push"=>nil, "last_update"=>"2019-12-26 10:03:45", "connector"=>{"sync_frequency"=>nil, "code"=>nil, "uuid"=>"3180ba23-2b75-5abe-b14d-69a42835474d", "documents_type"=>["bill"], "color"=>"c8ee20", "auth_mechanism"=>"credentials", "capabilities"=>["document"], "id"=>440, "available_auth_mechanisms"=>["credentials"], "beta"=>true, "months_to_fetch"=>nil, "urls"=>["https://addons.prestashop.com"], "siret"=>nil, "hidden"=>false, "charged"=>true, "slug"=>"PRE", "categories"=>[], "name"=>"PrestaShop"}, "active"=>true, "state"=>nil, "expire"=>nil, "accounts"=>[], "error"=>nil, "subscriptions"=>[{"id_source"=>699, "documents"=>[], "id_user"=>926, "deleted"=>nil, "id_connection"=>608, "number"=>"test01@gmail.com", "validity"=>nil, "label"=>"compere01@gmail.com", "subscriber"=>"John Doe", "currency"=>nil, "disabled"=>nil, "error"=>"bug", "id"=>550, "formatted_balance"=>nil, "renewdate"=>nil, "balance"=>nil, "last_update"=>nil}], "next_try"=>"2019-12-27 14:03:45", "id_connector"=>490, "id"=>908}, "push_type"=>"partial_history", "user"=>{"signin"=>"2019-12-26 10:03:08", "platform"=>"sharedAccess", "id"=>626}}}
```

Do you know how to display this `JSON` in my view ?

I tried, in my controller :

```
def webhooks
  render json: response.body, status: 200
  puts  response.body.inspect
end
```

But nothing happens in my view, I have the JSON in my console BUT my puts render an empty string.

Comment: You are getting `JSON` as params, 
you need to render params instead of `response.body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***params*** instead of ***response.body***

```
def webhooks
  render json: params, status: 200
  puts  params
end
```